# cannot load mat file into python with scipy.io or hdf5storage

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, mat

I have tried several ways to load my .mat file into python. I eventually want  the structure in the mat file to be a numpy array.  I am not sure how best to post this question, because I think I might need to upload my .mat file, as it seems there is a problem with that since the steps I am trying seemed to work for everyone else.

First, I tried:

```
 import scipy.io as sio
 mat_contents = sio.loadmat('filename.mat')
```

Which gave the same error message (listed below) as when I installed hdf5storage and h5py.  I have matlab version 9.3. and python 3.5.3.

This also gave the same error message as below:

```
  import hdf5storage
  mat = hdf5storage.loadmat('filename.mat')
```

The error from both those tries is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/u1/usr/.conda/envs/mypython/lib/python3.5/site-packages/hdf5storage/__init__.py", line 1801, in loadmat
    **keywords)
  File "/u1/usr/.conda/envs/mypython/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio.py", line 135, in loadmat
    MR = mat_reader_factory(file_name, appendmat, **kwargs)
  File "/u1/usr/.conda/envs/mypython/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio.py", line 59, in mat_reader_factory
    mjv, mnv = get_matfile_version(byte_stream)
  File "/u1/usr/.conda/envs/mypython/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/io/matlab/miobase.py", line 235, in get_matfile_version
    maj_ind = int(tst_str[2] == b'I'[0])
IndexError: index out of range
>>>
```

My .mat file contains a structure 1x1 which has several fields of different sizes.  I am mostly a python person, and am only using matlab to output files which I intend to analyze in python.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `hdf5storage`, but it looks like this call just uses the familiar `scipy.io.loadmat`.  This works for matlab files upto version 7.2.  Higher ones require the `h5py` loader.

Comment: Looking the `hdf5storage`, it looks like its `loadmat` tries the 7.3+ approach first, and reverts to `scipy.io` is that doesn't work.  Apparently the file doesn't work either way.  The format of the file seems to be the problem, not the details of the data structue.  Can you open it with `h5py`?

Comment: Your error is different from what I get when I try to use `io.loadmat` on a `h5` file.  So it probably is an 'old-style' file.  But I don't know why it's having problems reading the version number.

Answer (score 0):

@hpaulj thanks, your comment made me reload the file as I think it was somehow corrupted . I cannot trace what happened to it but the solution to this question was to check the file. The steps listed above in the question are correct. (I'm new to Stackoverflow and I'm pretty sure you cannot accept a comment as an answer so hopefully you will get credit here because I tagged your name?)